# Capturing ALL output text when running calc in linux terminal using Subprocess.popen

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a very simple task that I want to be done. All I want to is capture the output text when entering my program in linux terminal. Its similar to calc so I will use calc as an example.

So when I open the terminal in Linux and type calc i get this:

```
linux@linux-VirtualBox:~$ calc
C-style arbitrary precision calculator (version 2.12.7.2)
Calc is open software. For license details type:  help copyright
[Type "exit" to exit, or "help" for help.]

;
```

My goal is to capture all the text above and store it as stdout instead of displaying it in the terminal, so i can display it later.

I have tried all sorts of `subprocess.popen` variations. My latest try was this:

```py
import subprocess
executable = ['script', '-q', '/dev/null','/bin/sh', '-c', 'calc >/dev/tty']
p = subprocess.Popen(executable, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, text=True)
p.terminate()
out, err = p.communicate()
print ("---")
print ("output: ", out)
```

I want all the text to end up in the `out` variable